# how to use PWDENCRYPT in codeigniter model to check or compare password in sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I wonder how can I compare my user input data (ex. password) using codeigniter to the password in my SQL Server.

Here is the code of my model

```
function com_pass($username,$password){

    $ssql = "select * from cabal_auth_table where ID=? and Password=(PWDENCRYPT(?))";
    $query = $this->db->query($ssql, array($username,$password));
    if ($query->num_rows()>0){
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;    
}
```

and I have my table in the sql server cabal_auth_table which have a row field ID, Password, FirstName etc., now the password in sql is encrypted using PWDENCRYPT.

Is there a way that I can compare my data from user input to the one in sql server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

after how many hours I spend, finally solved it. I hope this will help you guys.

```
$query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cabal_auth_table WHERE ID='".$username."' AND PwdCompare('".$password."',Password) = 1 ");
```